# AADSTS70007: 'query' is not a supported value of 'response_mode' when requesting a token

Tags: azure, oauth, azure-active-directory, openid

So I created an application in Azure AD a few days ago. When requesting authorization code, I am getting the following error back when I ask for both `code` and `id_token` (in `response_type` parameter):

> AADSTS70007: 'query' is not a supported value of 'response_mode' when
>   requesting a token
>
> Trace ID: xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx
>
> Correlation ID: xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx
>
> Timestamp: 2018-06-13 16:06:03Z

My request URL looks something like this:

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?resource=https%3A%2F%2Fmanagement.core.windows.net%2F&client_id=application-client-id&response_type=code+id_token&redirect_uri=urn%3Aietf%3Awg%3Aoauth%3A2.0%3Aoob&response_mode=query&nonce=1528906255418&state=12345`

However, I don't get any errors if I only ask for `code` and not `id_token`. So essentially, following URL works:

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?resource=https%3A%2F%2Fmanagement.core.windows.net%2F&client_id=application-client-id&response_type=code&redirect_uri=urn%3Aietf%3Awg%3Aoauth%3A2.0%3Aoob&response_mode=query&nonce=1528906255418&state=12345`

What is even more interesting is that if I use a client id of an application created a few months ago, the code works perfectly fine and Azure AD returns me both `code` and `id_token`.

I did find one similar problem here: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/242669/aadsts70007-query-is-not-a-supported-value-of-response-mode-when-requesting but there was no answer provided for that question.

I'm curious to know:

- Why Azure AD does not throw any error for older application but for newer application? Has anything changed at the Azure AD level recently that will cause this problem? And that too for only newer applications.
- Is there a way to prevent this error from happening? I would very much like to use `query` as `response_mode` instead of `form_post`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Two different authorization flows:

- If you want to use `code + id_token` in the `response_type`,you should be using [OIDC Hybrid Flow](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#HybridFlowAuth).
- However, if you just use `code`in the `response_type`, you should be using [Authorization Code flow](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#CodeFlowSteps).

So, These two kinds of requests are different OIDC Authentication flow due to their different `response_type`s.

## Meanwhile, two different `response_mode`s:

- For `form_post`, `form_post` executes a POST containing the code to your redirect URI.When  the Authorization Response is intended to be used only once, you should use `form_post` in `reponse_mode`. You can also see the details about `form_post` in [this documentation](https://openid.net/specs/oauth-v2-form-post-response-mode-1_0.html#FormPostResponseMode).
- For `query`, In this mode, Authorization Response parameters are encoded in the query string added to the `redirect_uri` when redirecting back to the Client. For more details about `query` in `response_mode`, you can refer to [this documentation](https://openid.net/specs/oauth-v2-multiple-response-types-1_0.html#ResponseModes).

So, you may be more clear about the different `response_mode` for different Authorization flows.

For Authorization code flow, you can use `query` or `form_post`, For Hybird flow, you can use `form_post` or `fragment`. For web applications, we recommend using `response_mode=form_post`, to ensure the most secure transfer of tokens to your application. (the Microsoft OpenId Connect middleware only supports `hybrid` + `form_post`)

> Why Azure AD does not throw any error for older application but for
>   newer application? Has anything changed at the Azure AD level recently
>   that will cause this problem? And that too for only newer
>   applications.

I'm not 100% sure, but AAD shouldn't change anything about its authorization/authentication level. Maybe you used different types of App or authentication flow.

> Is there a way to prevent this error from happening? I would very much
>   like to use query as `response_mode` instead of `form_post`.

Since the reason is caused by OIDC framework, I think you cannot use `query` for hybird flow request.You'd better use `form_post`
in this flow if your app is a web app.

Additional, [Azure portal](https://portal.azure.com) is using this flow actually, but it may be a little different from what we can use. But you can see how the authentication/authorization works by catching its HTTP traffic via Fiddler. With this flow, you've to enable your App to allow implicit flow.

You can also see [this sample](https://github.com/mspnp/multitenant-saas-guidance) for Authenticate using Azure AD and OpenID Connect Hybrid flow in [this documentaion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/multitenant-identity/authenticate).

Comment: Many thanks @Wayne Yang for providing such detailed explanation! Let me read more about it and come back with any questions I may have.

Comment: Hi @GauravMantri , Please feel to let me know if you have any further questions about this case.;-)

Comment: You can also see this samplefor Authenticate using Azure AD and OpenID Connect Hybrid flow in [this documentaion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/multitenant-identity/authenticate).

Answer (score 1):

Adding an answer for the sake of completeness. Wayne's answer helped immensely!

So, instead of using `response_type=query`, I ended up using `response_type=fragment` and my new request URL now looks like the following:

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?resource=https%3A%2F%2Fmanagement.core.windows.net%2F&client_id=application-client-id&response_type=code+id_token&redirect_uri=urn%3Aietf%3Awg%3Aoauth%3A2.0%3Aoob&response_mode=fragment&nonce=1528906255418&state=12345`

And I was able to get both `code` and `id_token` back:
    urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob#code=code&id_token=id_token&state=12345&session_state=c6989d04-48ff-40cd-86ac-0cd2670ee168

Removed `urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob#` and then parsed the remaining string to get both `code` and `id_token` values in the application.

Comment: It's great! Cheers!