# Azure Single Sign On - Redirect Loop

Tags: php, azure, azure-active-directory

I have a problem setting up simple single sign on with Azure AD for our pHp website. The app is registered in azure and I have all the necessary details like Client ID, secret, tenant.

My requirement is to get authorized and also pull back the user's employee id, name and email id. I am working on single sign on for the first time, and need some help on this.

While creating the authorization URL, I am requesting for **code**, which is right according to the Azure documentation. I am successfully able to retrieve the code after authorization. However, I am not able to request **id_token** along with code as **response_type=code+id_token**, which should be possible. I could trace the URL flow and extract the **id_token** field manually. If I do this, I am prompted with the logon and MFA. But the response goes into infinite loop by just prompting with infinite number of MFA pings on my phone. This is weird, my program has a check to redirect on code response, which doesn't seem to work. I have tried using session_id cookie too, which has the same behavior.

If I just choose **code** as response type and request for **id_token** using token granting URL, I don't get any response back. Its blank or null but no errors.

Can you please help suggest if I am making a mistake. Is my method right or wrong to request code first and token next. How can I successfully retrieve id_token.

Comment: Can you see if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50842001/aadsts70007-query-is-not-a-supported-value-of-response-mode-when-requesting

Comment: Please share the document you are following and also refer the documentation for [PHP](https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-client/#authorization-code-grant)

Comment: @GauravMantri-AIS thanks. That post lead me to some standards, and could realize the mistake I was making. I had to use fragment while I used code+id_token. If we use fragment, the response is just stopped at browser and can't be handled on server. My code was wrong. So, I have taken the regular route to request code first using authorization url, and later requesting token using token url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just summary the comment into reply to help others who have the same problem.

`response_mode`: Specifies the method that should be used to send the resulting authorization code back to your app. Can be `form_post` or `fragment`. **For web applications, we recommend using `response_mode=form_post`**, to ensure the most secure transfer of tokens to your application.

If you want to use `code + id_token` in the `response_type`,you should be using OIDC Hybrid Flow.

However, if you just use `code` in the `response_type`, you should be using Authorization Code flow.

For more details, you could refer to this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50842001).